# If $(1 + x)^{10} = 2.5$, what is $x$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

If

$$(1 + x)^{10} = 2.5$$

, the next step would be

$$10 * \log(1 + x) = \log(2.5)$$

$$\log(1 + x) = \frac{\log(2.5)}{10}$$

. This is where I am stuck. I know that

$$\log_{b}(a + c) = \log_{b}(a) + \log_b\left( 1 + \frac{c}{a} \right)$$

, but that does not help me in any way.

Comment: Just exponentiate both sides to get rid of the $\log$ on the left.

Comment: Alternatively: if $(1+x)^{10} = 2.5$ then $1+x$ is $2.5^{1/10}$. Subtract one.

Comment: This isn't quite true. $\log (1+x)^{10} = 10\cdot \log |1+x|$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the unknown isn't the exponent, but the base, then logarithms aren't the most natural solution. Roots are:
$$
(1+x)^{10} = 2.5\\
1+x = \pm\sqrt[10]{2.5}\\
x = -1\pm\sqrt[10]{2.5}
$$

Comment: Roots of $2.5$ maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Sure. That might be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Just, $$x=2.5^{0.1}-1$$ or $$x=-2.5^{0.1}-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$(1+x)^{10} = 2.5$                  (original equation)

$1+x = \sqrt[10]{2.5} $            (take 10th root of both sides)

$1+x = \pm1.09596... $             (simplify)

$x = 0.09596...$                      (subtract 1 on both sides, positive root)

or

$x = -2.09596... $                    (subtract 1 on both sides, negative root)

Answer (score 0):

If the equation $\log(1+x) = \frac{\log(2.5)}{10}$ holds then this equation holds no matter what base the logs were taken in (as long as the logs on both sides were taken to same base). Make sure you see why.

Calculate $a=\log_e(2.5)$. Then $1+x = e^{a/10}$ which gives $x= e^{a/10}-1$.

If you are more comfortable working base 10, then

$a=\log_{10}(2.5)$. Then $1+x = 10^{a/10}$ which gives $x= 10^{a/10}-1$.

---

ETA: you should check that this answer and Arthur's above give the same result.

Comment: Taking logarithms is ok, but arriving at $\log(1+x) = \frac{\log(2.5)}{10}$ is not. We drop a solution by saying that $\log(1+x)^{10} = 10\log(1+x)$ instead of $\log(1+x)^{10} = 10\log|x+1|$

Comment: You are correct @Jakobian